# Percentage and numeric relations

Tags: percentages

I would like to know the simplest approach to the followings:

**Que 1:**

One student scored $14$ marks more than the other and his marks were $60$% of the sum of their marks. Find marks obtained **by them**.

**My Approach:**

Step 1: Assuming students scored $x$ and $x+14$.

Step 2: $x+14$ is $60$% of sum of their marks i.e. $2x+14$, so $x$ is $40$%.

Don't know further.

**Ans: 28 and 42** I know the answer but don't know how to achieve.

**Que 2:**

Two persons are paid total $9.2$ Dollars per week.  $1st$  is paid $260$% more than amount paid to $2nd$. Find their payment for week.

**Ans: 2 and 7.2** I know the answer but don't know how to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A percentage is just a different way of writing a number.
People do not like to say things like $0.4$, so instead they
multiply the number by $100$ and attach a percentage sign to it.
That is, by definition,

$$ 0.4 = 40\%.$$

People find it much more agreeable to say $40\%$ than to say $0.4$.
They also prefer very much to say "$40\%$ of something" rather than
"$40\%$ times something", although if you regard $40\%$ as a number
(as I do) then the two phrases mean the same thing.

This is all fine
until it comes time to actually do some arithmetic on the number.
Then I personally find that usually the first thing I would like to do is
to write $40\%$ as $0.4$, and say "times" rather than "of",
and then never think about percentages again.

So for the first problem you found the following:

- The sum of the marks is $2x + 14$.
- $x$ is $0.4$ times the sum of the marks

If you introduce a symbol such as $s$ to represent "the sum of the marks", from the two statements above you can derive two equations which are easy
to solve for $x$.

For the second problem, when people say something like "$x$ is $10\%$ more than $y$", they mean that $x$ is $y$ plus another $0.1$ times $y$, or
$x = y + 0.1y = 1.1y$.

That is, "$10\%$ more than" is a way people like to say "$1.1$ times",
"$20\%$ more than" is a way people like to say "$1.2$ times",
"$50\%$ more than" is a way people like to say "$1.5$ times",
and so forth.

So what does "$260\%$ more than" mean?

Now if $x$ is the wages of the lesser-paid worker, and the other
worker is paid $260\%$ more than $x$, and the two wages add up to $9.2$,
you can write a single easily-solved equation with one unknown $x$.

Answer (score 2):

First question:

You are correct, $x$ is $40\%$ of the sum of their marks, and the sum of their marks is $2x+14$.

Now, you need to transform that into an equation.

In general, if $a$ is equal to $p\%$ of $b$ (for example, if "my height" is equal to $90\%$ of "your height"), you know that the **ratio** between $a$ and $b$, multiplied by $100$, is equal to $p$ (i.e., my height, divided by your height, times $100$, is $90$).

Now, answer these questions (in that order):

- how would you write the relation "**ratio** between $a$ and $b$, multiplied by $100$, is equal to $p$" as an equation?
- In your case, what is $a$ and what is $b$, and what is $p$?
- So in your case, what equation do you get?
- How do you solve this equation?

---

Second question:

Say the first person is paid $x$, and the second one is paid $y$. Then, transform the following two statements into equations:

- They are paid $9.2$ dollars in total.
- The pay of the first person is $260\%$ *more* than the pay of the second person.

What equations do you get?